# Getting a lock on a single dictionary entry instead of whole dictionary?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locks

Say I have a `static Dictionary<string, object>` and want to do something like the following, except I only want to lock the specific dictionary entry that I'm currently dealing with instead of the entire dictionary:

```
lock(myDictionary)
{
   if(myDictionary["myKey"] == null)
   {
      myDictionary["myKey"] = new MyClass();
   }
}
```

Is this possible without writing my own Dictionary implementation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the new [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) class.  It effectively provides thread safety by locking in a much finer grained manner than locking on the entire dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about this. I am actually trying to update an ASP.NET application to make thread-safe use of Session state, and was hoping there was a way to get a lock on just part of the Session object rather than the whole thing. It's looking like I'm gonna have to write my own SessionState implementation.

Comment: @nw Are you sure the ASP.NET session state *really is a problem* from the concurrency point of view? Rather first read the “Concurrent Requests and Session State” paragraph at the bottom of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx.

Comment: The main problem I am trying to fix is that requests from the same session are queued, so the server blocks for long periods of time after canceling an ajax request. When I started this thread I was thinking there would be a way to turn this queuing off and that I could manage the concurrency myself, but apparently that is difficult or not possible. The session state is only used to store one cache object per session. Now I am thinking the easiest solution is to just put a ConcurrentDictionary in the Application State that maps the Session ID to the cache object. What do you think?

Comment: @nw: You could try doing that, but then you'd run into the issue of making sure that it clears out appropriately, or you'd cause a memory leak.  If you can get that portion working correctly, it should, technically, work.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In your case it makes no sense to “lock the specific dictionary entry” only; even if you write your own implementation. If you don't know if the entry exists and you want to add it into the dictionary in such a case, you will always have to synchronize access to the dictionary's control structures. In other words, even if you implement it yourself, there will be a need to synchronize access to at least a certain portion of its internal structures.

Comment: I was hoping there was a specific part of the dictionary's internal structure that I could get a lock on. Is the dictionary implemented with some sort of hash table? If the hash of the key was an index into an array of Lists (to handle hash collisions), for example, then I could put a lock on the specific List associated with my key, correct?

Comment: Yes, depending on the particular technical implementation, the dictionary would have to lock on some specific substructure.